# How can I take a screenshot of the notification bar dropdown?

Tags: notification-bar, screenshots

Sometimes I get a notification in the notification bar, I pull it down, and then I want to take a screenshot. I press the power button to make the screenshot, a menu appears to either shutdown, restart or make a screenshot. When this popup menu appears, the pulldown menu disappears. I've tried another screenshot app, but that didn't work either.

**How can I take a screenshot of the notification pulldown menu?**

Comment: Isn't the normal way (volume down + power button) working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, but there's a workaround I came up with. Using the screen recorder, make a short video where you scroll down the notifications bar. Once the notification you want to screencap is in frame, end the recording, play the video, pause it, and then take a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You just have press and hold volume down and home key for some time

Comment: This isn't an answer. When I take a screenshot, I press the power button on my phone, then a menu pops up where I can choose to restart or make a screenshot. When this menu appears, the dropdown disappears.

Comment: @SPRBRN You have to press the power button and the volume down button at the same time. Then the menu should not appear. If it still appears the device manufacturer has destroyed the screenshot function, because on a AOSP device it works.

Comment: Confirm this works on my Google Pixel.

Comment: Works on Google Pixel Android 14